# Python IF statement is giving "invalid syntax" error. Please let me know what could be the reason

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, compiler-errors

Please let me know the cause of invalid syntax error in my if statement. The error is pointing under the "if" particularly.

```
random_integer = random.randint(0,10)
i=3

while (i != 0):
  try:
    number = int(input("Enter your number between 0 to 10: "))

    if number > random_integer:
        print("Your number is greater than my number.")
        i -= 1
        print("You have now {} chance(s) left".format(i))

    elif number < random_integer:
        print("Your number is smaller than my number.")
        i -= 1
        print("You have now {} chance(s) left".format(i))

    elif number == random_integer:
        print("Congratulations! you guessed the correct number. You won the Game.")
        print("Thanks for playing.")
        break


  except:
    print("please enter an integer number from 0 to 10. Try again")
```

Comment: Indent the `if`, or the `try` will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Please pay attention to indentation when writing python code.

Comment: You can use python online validators to check your code, e.g. http://pep8online.com/. It says you have 6 errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error you are getting (as other people have mentioned) is because of indentation (or lack of) within your code.

Python is different from other languages by the fact that it does not use semicolons (;) or curly brackets ({}) to mark an end of line or start/end of a code block.

What it does do, is identify lines of code based on the amount of spaces before each line.
Typically, this means that when you open a block of code, you need to indent the lines after it, to indicate that the following lines of code are related to that specific code block.

In your case, you have started a try/catch block, but have not indented the code after it, so your IDE does not know that it is part of the try/catch block.

You can fix this, by indenting the lines relevant to your try/catch block by pressing tab once or spacebar FOUR times.

```
while (i <= 3):
   try:
       number = int(input("Enter your number between 0 to 10:" ))

       if number > random_integer:
           print("Your number is greater than my number.")
           print("You have now {} chance(s) left".format(i-1))

       elif number < random_integer:
           print("Your number is smaller than my number.")
           print("You have now {} chance(s) left".format(i-1))

       elif number == random_integer:
           print("Congratulations! you guessed the correct number. You won teh Game.")
           print("Thanks for playing.")
           break
```